# How can I add more than 200 columns in Google Cloud SQL table

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

So I'm creating a table in Google Cloud SQL having 272 columns in it. But at the time of table creation, I'm getting following error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.
```

Then I came across this post on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/327222/326310) and tried to set the same flags on Google Cloud SQL via Google Cloud Platform Dashboard, but I can't find them in the `Add database flags` section.

Can anybody help me please. Thank you.

Comment: What is the current value of `SELECT @@innodb_file_format`? It might already be Barracuda. The default on MySQL 5.7 is Barracuda, the default on MySQL 5.6 is Antelope.

Comment: @BillKarwin It is `Barracuda`

Comment: So you already have the option to use Barracuda formats. You need to declare `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` or `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` if you want to use that row format (the table implicitly uses Barracuda for that row format). I'm not sure this will reduce the row size enough to resolve your error, though.

Comment: @BillKarwin It did not work

Comment: Did it work for anyone? I am getting this error on import "ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 103: Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline.". People say that change a few flags but they are not supported.